# Integrating JMeter performance tests with Jenkins CI

Tags: performance, testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, jmeter

I'm working on integrating performance tests with CI/CD infrastructure. My performance testing tool is JMeter and CI server is Jenkins. Both can do their jobs, but when it comes to integrating performance tests in CI/CD pipeline, things are no longer so trivial.

To have proper deployment pipeline CI server needs to know when a performance test build should be considered passed or failed. Verification of mean average of response times is not a good option - completely different SLAs can apply to different types of transactions executed as part of the same JMX file. Asserting on mean average of response times for particular transaction type is a far better option, but it is still far from a perfect solution. This won't tell us e.g. if response times for same type of transaction are increasing (which can has something to do with memory leaks) or decreasing (which can be a blessing of server-side cache). For that reason, relying only on mean avg response times can create false confidence in software quality.

I analysed a couple of tools, including JMeter Maven Analysis Plugin and Jenkins Performance Plugin. None of them seems to offer what I'm looking for.

In pre-CI era, performance tests were executed late in the development lifecycle and analysed by a human being. I wonder if anyone came across any advance enough tool, which can make it possible for CI server to reliably determine if perf test build should be marked as passed or failed, without verification of results by a human?

Comment: but then what are your criteria of deciding manually if tests are failed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of tools offering what I'm looking for, I've decided to kick off an open source project create one on my own, in my free time:

https://github.com/automatictester/lightning

It's still in its early days, but the core functionality is there. Now it's a matter of time to extend it with extras.

Comment: why does the jenkins performance plugin fall short? I've setup jenkins jobs where maven or gradle runs jmeter tests and the performance plugin displays trends and marks builds passed failed or unstable based on parsed jmeter results.

Comment: When I was evaluating Jenkins Performance Plugin, I encountered a couple of issues. Instead of getting graphs I was looking for, I was getting stack traces, including those two:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27526
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27547

Long story short: Performance Plugin didn't give me what it promised, so that I didn't even get to the point when I could assess if I can use it to pass or fail the build.

Comment: However, I don't think it can give me what I'm looking for. According to its documentation, it can pass/fail build depending on error percentage. This is very basic check, almost health check, and I'm interested in more detailed verification of results - including e.g. average response time per transaction type.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Jenkins expert but only mildly skilled with JMeter.  Can your JMeter results be processed by a script in order to tell when Transaction Type Z passes beyond the acceptable time limit for the run?

It looks like parsing the jmeter results with some additional logic is what you need to be able to bubble up an exit(1) (or any non-zero) value.

Comment: This is what I end up with at the moment. I parse JMeter output with awk to get the basic stats and play with it later on. But this is more makeshift than an clean solution. I am wondering if other people came to similar conclusion and maybe came across tools which can do this (and much more) for them.